# Pandas: Assign Dataframe to Dataframe Slice

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

recently I encountered unexpected behaviour in pandas and I would like to ask why that works as it works.

Here is the code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'party_id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], 
     'date_valid': [6, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 0, 8, 7, 9], 
     'target': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
     }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)        
                                           
df=df.sort_values(['party_id','date_valid'],ascending=True)  # sorts the rows
df['lag_target'] = df.groupby(['party_id'])['target'].shift(1)  # computes the lagged column
df.loc[df['lag_target'].isnull(),'lag_target'] = df['target']  # replaces nan with values from the original target
print(df)
```

Firsly, I thought that pandas keeps track of the index (or grouped index), however, you can create another dataframe DF2 and it will work the same as above. What baffles me is that on LHS is slice of Dataframe with 4 rows and on RHS is bigger Dataframe and it still connects the correct rows. Why?

Comment: your question is unclear, yes assignment keeps track of the index, but your `groupby.shift` occurs in order of the rows. What would be your expected output?

Comment: Actually, I expected an error since on the RHS is dataframe with 10 rows. However, on the LHS due to the .loc[] there is dataframe with only 4 rows. How can you assing bigger dataframe to smaller one?

Comment: OK, this is not an issue, you can assign a bigger or smaller dataframe without issue, pandas will align the indices and discard/fill the extra/missing values. You cannot do this with arrays/lists however. Please let me know if this is sufficient to you, else I can write a more complete answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate, please? Let´s assume that I create another dataframe df2, the same as df1, though. And it will still work. I frankly don´t understand why? For me, it would make sense to have the same condition on both sides.

Comment: And why this doesn´t work: df[df['lag_target'].isnull()]["lag_target"] = df['target']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works as expected:

```
# assign the shifted values per group
df['lag_target'] = df.groupby(['party_id'])['target'].shift(1) 

# replace the NaN with the values from targer
df.loc[df['lag_target'].isnull(), 'lag_target'] = df['target']
```

For the last command, the left hand side is indeed shorter than the right hand side, but this isn't an issue for pandas as only the indices from the LHS that are in the RHS will be used.

Note that you could replace your code with:

```
df['lag_target'] = df.groupby('party_id')['target'].shift(1).fillna(df['target'])
```

Output:

```
   party_id  date_valid  target  lag_target
2         1           1       2         2.0
1         1           2       1         2.0
0         1           6       0         1.0
3         2           3       3         3.0
4         2           4       4         3.0
5         3           5       5         5.0
6         4           0       6         6.0
8         4           7       8         6.0
7         4           8       7         8.0
9         4           9       9         7.0
```

Breaking down the logic, here is the LHS part:

```
df.loc[df['lag_target'].isnull(),'lag_target']

2   NaN
3   NaN
5   NaN
6   NaN
Name: lag_target, dtype: float64
```

So when assigning, only the indices 2/3/5/6 of the RHS will be used, if any is missing NaN will be assigned instead.

Comment: So the assignment is done through the index and not through the actual dataframe. Ok. But why without the ".loc" it doesn't work? 
df[df['lag_target'].isnull()]["lag_target"] = df['target']

Comment: Oh, and thank you. I actually spend couple of hours on pandas documentation yesterday and found there similar answer, but was kinda confused. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `df[df['lag_target'].isnull()]["lag_target"]` doesn't work because the double slicing creates a copy, so you update a copy that immediately disappears, you should always use `loc` for assignement: `df.loc['lag_target'].isnull(), "lag_target"]` ;)